# Change name of customer account page

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I want to change the name of the 'My Downloadable Products' page to 'Recipes'. I want this to be changed in the navigation, and the page title.

Is there a way to achieve this, other than to translate the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***For change navigation title in customer account,***

**app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Downloadable/layout/customer_account.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link">             
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">downloadable/customer/products</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Recipes</argument>
            </arguments>            
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Downloadable/layout/downloadable_customer_products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
     <title>Recipe</title>
   </head>
</page>
```

Comment: The menu item did change to Recipe, but the page title is still the same :/

Comment: i have updated answer please check.

Comment: I meant the page title :p

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya These files should go in **app|code|Vendorname|Themename|view|frontend|layout**, isn't it?

Comment: yes correct path is,  Magento_Downloadable/layout/

Answer (score 0):

To change the page title:
**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Downloadable/layout/downloadable_customer_products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Recipe</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```